# FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: This app does not have permission to access Firebase Storage on this project

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security, firebase-app-check

I've got such strange problem. I've got properly configured Firebase App with firebase iOS, android and web app. Everything were good and access to storage were without any problems but since something strange happened to billing account inside firebase, something strange started happening.
After everything were reconfigured again with billing account and selecting again Blaze plan I've started to receive such error -> `FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: This app does not have permission to access Firebase Storage on this project`
Whole error message is below:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: This app does not have permission to access Firebase Storage on this project. (storage/unauthorized-app)
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."
  }
}
```

This problems occurs on android, iOS and web app.
I've another firebase project with the same app for test purposes and there is no problem with that. I'm sure that this isn't problem with rules in storage because I've got the same configuration inside these 2 projects on firebase.
Could you help me with resolving this issue? I'm stuck here and I haven't found any answer how to repair it.

Comment: From the error message it sounds like you're [enforcing App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) on the project, but not all clients are sending App Check tokens yet. Are you using an older SDK on the clients by any chance?

Comment: Hey Frank, I'm using FirebaseAppCheck with Flutter. Building an iOS app in release mode from my laptop works perfectly but building an Android app in release mode fails to talk to Firestore because of AppCheck. I'm running on physical devices, not emulators/simulators.

Any clue why Android release builds might be failing to talk to Firestore? The build is from the latest code i.e. the one that's already sending the AppCheck token to Firebase.

Comment: SOLVED! I was using a STG Firebase Project and PROD Firebase Project but had the SHA256 from the PROD PlayStore project on the both Firebase projects. 

I replaced the STG SHA256 with the one generated locally using keytool and after 15 minutes, Android STG release builds were working again ⭐️